# How to make template function call with variadic template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Below is my simple variadic template function. This template takes std::tuple as one of its input parameter. But it refuses to compile with the error "template argument deduction/substitution failed".

Can anyone please point me to the error I am making?

```
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template<typename... TT, typename ReturnType>
ReturnType& getValue(int ind, std::tuple<TT...>& t, ReturnType& val) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return val;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    std::string str("Hello"), result;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    std::tuple<std::string> t = std::make_tuple(str);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    getValue<std::tuple<std::string>, std::string>(0, t, result);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Below is the compilation output.

```
g++ -c tuple.cc -std=c++1z; g++ -o tuple tuple.o
tuple.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
tuple.cc:15:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘getValue(int, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, std::__cxx11::string&)’
     getValue<std::tuple<std::string>, std::string>(0, t, result);
                                                                ^
tuple.cc:7:13: note: candidate: template<class ... TT, class ReturnType> ReturnType& getValue(int, std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ReturnType&)
 ReturnType& getValue(int ind, std::tuple<TT...>& t, ReturnType& val) {
             ^
tuple.cc:7:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tuple.cc:15:64: note:   mismatched types ‘std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’
     getValue<std::tuple<std::string>, std::string>(0, t, result);
                                                                ^
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getValue(0, t, result);
```

that will compile.  `...TT` is not a tuple, it is `std::string`.

You tried to call it with `...TT` being `std::tuple<std::string>, std::string, ...` which of course does not match `std::string`.

Comment: There were couple of more elements in tuple which I removed while debugging the error.

So, I should always call without template function without template parameters if one of the parameters is tuple?

Comment: @unsat no, that is not the rule.  But let it deduce if it can.  And it often can.

Comment: Last follow up question :) 
How would the explicit parameterized template function call look like?

Comment: @UnSat It isn't possible; you have template parameters following a pack.

Comment: This is interesting for me. It is the case where template parameter type deduction works but parameter type substitution does not.